# Discard similar looking images from a group of images

Tags: python, node.js, image, image-processing

I am looking to differentiate between images. I want to:

- Detect similar images
- Detect dissimilar images

I have tried some libraries that could help me with this task. Some of them are :

- [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html?highlight=difference)
- [Pixel Match](https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch)
- [Looks Same](https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same)

Pillow for instance has methods to help me differentiate and I also wrote the following code with Pillow:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageStat

im = Image.open("./thumbnails/out01.jpg");
im2 = Image.open("./thumbnails/out29.jpg");

#print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im, im2)

print('size : ', diff.size)

bbox = diff.getbbox()

print('bbox ',bbox)

diff.save('diff.jpg') # save the diff image

cropped = diff.crop(bbox)
cropped.save('cropped.jpg') # save the cropped image after bbox

stats = ImageStat.Stat(diff)
print('mean',stats.mean)
print('median',stats.median)
print('variance',stats.var)
```

but could not find the way to tell if the two have images are very similar or are very different.

I am generating thumbnails from a video using `FFMPEG` and I need to discard the very similar looking thumbnails. How could I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're asking for an algorithm or metric by which you can define "similarity", this may not be the best place to get answers.  That's a pretty broad question whose answer is subjective and will depend on your use case.  Questions on here are generally more along the lines of "I'm trying to do X, here is some code that is failing, why is it failing?"  Best of luck, though!

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 Is there a way I could do this with Pillow?

Comment: Start with some research into perceptual-hashing. There is probably nothing in pillow, but i think even ffmpeg has something for you (but maybe hard to use). As most perceptual-hashes output some bit-vector you can then pick the most diverging in terms of their hamming-distance. The latter is maybe even not that easy (maybe NP-hard), but heuristics might be enough. E.g. cluster all img-hashes and pick one from each class (to keep). Do not start with subtracting pixels! That's not going anywhere (noise and co; although you got the luxury of constant dimensions)!